# Same Wiki for several projects on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, wiki

I'm using Gitlab and I've several projects.

project1;
project2;
project3;

Is it possible to have a common Wiki for these projects?

Comment: Currently not, maybe you should file a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Every wiki is linked to a project, but there is a workaround:

Go to Settings → Services → External Wiki for your 2nd and 3rd projects and set `External wiki URL` to the URL of your first project wiki:
[image]

Or you can host your own wiki, for example, [gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum) on your server for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a common Wiki for these projects?

Yes: (October 2020, 4 years later)
[GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#group-wikis) proposes:

> ### Group wikis
>
> For many teams, using GitLab wikis for planning and documentation is a critical part of their workflow. Wikis are so popular that they get over a million views each month on GitLab.com. Despite this popularity, teams have struggled with the limitation that wikis were only available at the project level.
> Teams working on multiple projects needed to create separate wikis for each repository, leading to a fragmented experience.
>
> In Gitlab 13.5, we are so excited to bring you **group wikis**!
>
> With [680 upvotes](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/13195) this was the most upvoted feature in the entire GitLab backlog. While highly requested, making a large project-only feature like wikis available at the group level has been a non-trivial operation. We’ve worked tirelessly over the past year to make it happen and now we can’t wait to get it in your hands and hear your feedback.
>
> Group-level wikis open up tons of possibilities to keep your information at a higher level and accessible to a broader set of people. A few examples of what you can put in your group wikis include team-specific information, coding style guides, and designs for your brand or your company.
>
> We know a lot of folks have been looking forward to this feature and shared their input pre-release. We hope all of you will continue to weigh in now that group wikis are available and we’ve opened up a [dedicated issue for your feedback](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/267593).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_5/cdybenko-group-wiki.png -- Group wikis]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/index.html#group-wikis) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/13195).

---

See [GitLab 16.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/07/22/gitlab-16-2-released/#group-level-wiki-now-available-in-advanced-search) (July 2023) adds (for premium or ultimate only):

> ### Group-level wiki now available in Advanced Search
>
> With this release, we’ve extended Advanced Search to include [group-level wikis](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/group.html). Users will now be able to find content in these wikis more easily and quickly than before.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/336100).