# Project Documentation: Create wiki pages, or create Markdown files in the repo?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Should I be using the Wiki functionality of Github/Gitlab, or should I create Markdown files within the repo?(or both?)

I've opted for the Markdown files because I don't know if the wiki pages are portable, or how to access them offline. Also, I have images that are referred to by their relative paths. I'm not sure where the wiki pages are stored and how to use relative paths instead of absolute paths.

Comment: The wiki pages, at least in GitLab, can be accessed as a git repository, so yes, you can access them offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki pages *are* markdown pages.

GitLab proposes [Wiki-specific Markdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/markdown.html#wiki-specific-markdown)  with, for instance, `[Link to File](file.md)` as a way to point to a file, relative to the current page.

GitHub, for instance, explains how to [add images from your repo into your wiki page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/), again in markdown.

Both explain how to access/clone/update your wiki:

- [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/):

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY.wiki.git
  ```
- [GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17643)

  ```
  git clone https://source.example.com/group/project.wiki.git
  ```

Comment: There is also a "group wiki" with GitLab 13.5 (Oct. 2020) but without Git URL yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64506695/6309